# Laravel - How to represent Email with a declared variable in Query function

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 project I have this Query function in the Controller:

```
public function sendemail($contact)
{
    $data = [
        'name'=> $contact['name'],
        'email'=> $contact['email'],
        'subject'=> $contact['subject'],
        'message'=> $contact['message']
    ];
    $site_email = InfoSite::select('email')->first();
    if(!$site_email) return $this->error("Site Contact Email does not exist", 404);

  Mail::send('mail', $data, function($mail_message) {
     $mail_message->to('lamptey@gmail.com')
                ->subject($data->subjects);
     $mail_message->from($data->email);
  });
}
```

How do I replace **lamptey@gmail.com** with **$site_email**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  pass the `$site_email` variable with [use()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) method :

```
$site_email = InfoSite::select('email')->first();
if(!$site_email) return $this->error("Site Contact Email does not exist", 404);

  Mail::send('mail', $data, function($mail_message)  use ($site_email) {
     $mail_message->to($site_email->email)
                ->subject($data->subjects);
     $mail_message->from($data->email);
  });
}
```